# R violin plot (vioplot) does not display data of same value

Tags: r, violin-plot

I am trying to create a violin plot of results of a survey, and everything looks fine, expect for those cases where all respondents submitted the same answer. In these cases, vioplot displays nothing, and I changed from vioplot to boxplot to have at least a line where the answers are.

My code:

```
plot(1,1,xlim=c(0,10),ylim=range(c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9)),type="n",
 xlab="",ylab="",axes=FALSE)
axis(side = 1, at=2,label="")
axis(side = 1, at=5,label="")
axis(side = 1, at=8,label="")

axis(side=2)
vioplot(x1,at=1,col="blue",add=TRUE)
vioplot(x2,at=2,col="red",add=TRUE)
vioplot(x3,at=3,col="yellow",add=TRUE)
vioplot(x4,at=4,col="blue",add=TRUE)
vioplot(x5,at=5,col="red",add=TRUE)
vioplot(x6,at=6,col="yellow",add=TRUE)
boxplot(x7,at=7,col="blue", add=TRUE)
boxplot(x8,at=8,col="red",add=TRUE)
vioplot(x9,at=9,col="yellow",add=TRUE)
```

This is what it looks like with boxplot, using vioplot instead, the whole column is empty.

[image]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong and what the code should be like so that I can use a vioplot?

Comment: If you don't have any variation then it makes sense to have a plot like that. You aren't doing anything wrong.

Comment: The issue is that the color marks the category in which the question is asked, so the user will not be able to see in which category the respondents submitted the same answer because I just have a black line. I could paint it in Photoshop but that's the last thing I want to do :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a quick play with the package. There aren't many options, doesn't look like it handles these cases well. You could try jitter on the data to create some small random noise for the graph e.g.

```
library(data.table)
library(vioplot)

cdt <- setDT(copy(cars))
cdt[, new := 16]

vioplot(cdt$speed, cdt$dist, jitter(cdt$new, 0.0001))
```

My preferable suggestion is to try out geom_violin in ggplot2 package.

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-violin-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization

Prettier and more functional :)

p.s. sorry if you don't use data.table; I don't code out of it now :)

Comment: cdt[,vioplot(speed, dist, jitter(new, 0.0001)),]